# Decrypt password in pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven

I have a util class that picks up properties from `application.properties`(jdbc password are in encrypted format in it) file and `encrypts/decrypts` it. I there a way to  `decrypt` the password while using placeholders in pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

For, `Decrypt password in pom.xml` you need to create Create master password with below commands :

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password
```

Once you run this command then, create a file called `~/.m2/settings-security.xml` and write below content into this file :

```
<settingsSecurity>
  <master><!-- result of above command --></master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

after this encrypt your password by rum below commands :

```
mvn --encrypt-password
```

after running this command you will get the output, you need to create a file `/.m2/settings.xml` and  write this output in your maven settings `~/.m2/settings.xml`. you can use below sample code to write into `/.m2/settings.xml`.

```
<settings>
...
  <servers>
  ...
    <server>
      <id>test.server</id>
      <username><!-- your database username --></username>
      <password><!-- the encrypted password --></password>
    </server>
  ...
  </servers>
...
</settings>
```

for more you can refer [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) link.

use below `sql-maven-plugin` with the configuration into `pom.xml`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT required -->
  <configuration>
    <settingsKey>test.server</settingsKey> <!-- id of server here -->
    <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip.com:1521:SID</url>
    <!-- username and password are not mentioned anymore -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: is it possible to do so using a custom plugin?